# Command "generate:module", is not a valid command name

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-console

When running following command for generating module using the drupal console on MacBook air

drupal generate: module

facing this error - **[ERROR] Command "generate: module", is not a valid command name.**

Comment: do you have drupal console installed globally? Are you sure you want the space between generate and module? [The docs](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/generate-module.html) don't have a space

Comment: yes drupal console install globally and also drupal generate:module i have run this command but again showing this  [ERROR] Command "generate:module", is not a valid command name.                

Thanks for @2pha for comments that can give me the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you're running the command from a folder outside of your Drupal document root, or if you're inside the document root but your web server isn't running.